# nmap command - suspicious behavior

Tags: networking, nmap

I'm learning Linux on Cisco, and they display a certain message about the `nmap` command :

> CAUTION: To avoid suspicion of using the tool to find a way to attack
>   the systems on your network, it is recommended that you obtain
>   authorization before using the nmap command.

Could anyone be able to tell me why is it dangerous? Could we use `nmap` to hack a computer?

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! on Stack Exchange we prefer one question per post; therefore, I've edited out your question about `www.example.com` feel free to ask a second question. see also [ask].

Comment: You've accepted an answer here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/858241/nmap-command-suspicious-behavior/858248#858248. Since you seem to believe this is Ubuntu-specific, isn't that answer enough?

Comment: @JohnN nice find. voting to close as cross-posting is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @SandraRoss in the future, please only add the Ubuntu tag if your question is specific to Ubuntu. I removed it for a reason - this question is applicable to all Unix/Linux distributions, so the tag is inappropriate. thanks!

Comment: This user is constantly spamming us, duplicating questions multiple times when it gets no answers [to his liking], and posts constantly off topic questions. It also posted a very nice picture of "her" macbook screen in which the reflection shows an indian guy with a moustache.

Answer (score 1):

`nmap` is (IIRC) a very flexible tool, but usually it's used to discover what's running on a remote system. Mostly the way it does this is by connecting to all ports on that system and guessing what's running on them based on things like what's sent upon `nmap` connecting. This is a process known as portscanning.

There aren't exactly a huge amount of legitimate uses for portscanning, especially if the remote host (or network) isn't your own. Therefore a lot of admins, upon discovering that their systems are being portscanned (or used to portscan another system), will assume that someone is trying to discover information about a remote system for malicious purposes.

So to answer your question more directly, `nmap` by itself isn't dangerous and can't be used to break into another computer. However, the process of breaking into a computer includes discovering as much information as possible about said computer (in order to reason about where its weaknesses may be). `nmap` is an extremely popular choice for (part of) that process - that's why some network/systems administrators will get ticked off if they notice you using it.